# Kollel avreichim who are not learning (properly) are rodfim?

Tags: sources-mekorot, chazon-ish

I was told that Rav Amnon Yitzchak quoted the Chazon Ish saying that men in kollel who are not learning properly (or something to that effect) are considered rodfim.

Can anyone source this Chazon Ish?

Comment: Who are they trying to kill? They're obviously thieves, of course.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sarcasm?

Comment: No. If you slack off at work you're stealing from your employer. This is obvious. If an alleged talmid chacham does this with a kollel then they are also creating a chillul hashem which only death atones for. אוי לו לרבו שלימדו תורה

Comment: I misunderstood your original comment. I thought you were saying that men in kollel are thieves.

Comment: Well there's the issue of sofo lilastem es habrios. But that's a general umbrella for anyone not involved with making a living.

Comment: probably out of context. something like Chizkiyahu's sword. http://ohr.edu/this_week/the_weekly_daf/119

Comment: What kind of source would you consider valid?

Comment: @Rish Maybe somewhere in the writings of the Chazon Ish or a quote fomr someone he heard the Chazon Ish say such a thing. Anything closer to the source would be a good step I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for this quote (or one of the variations on it that are floating around):

> ״כל מי שמנצל לרעה את זכות הדחייה של תלמידי הישיבות, הרי הוא בבחינת רודף, וחוטא כלפי בני הישיבות״

Anyone who wrongly exploits the 'yeshiva student' [draft] deferral is considered like a *rodef*, and sins against the [actual] *bnei yeshivot*.

The internet in several places attributes this line to the Chazon Ish "as quoted by the *menahel Vaad haYeshivot*, Rabbi M. Tenenbaum."  (Sometimes adding: in the newspaper *Erev Shabbat* 11.12.87. This formulation is found in the קונטרס תורתו-אמנותו of Shlomo Benizri, and others claim to have heard it from R' Tenenbaum directly, but those 'others' are semi-anonymous internet people. I also have not actually seen the newspaper that is being cited.)  The quote from the Chazon Ish is also supposedly quoted in *Pe’er Hador,* vol. 4, p. 260; if anyone has access to this book, it would be great if you could confirm this.

(I've seen R' Tenenbaum described as a talmid of the Chazon Ish, but again, not anywhere particularly reliable.)

Comment: This answer could be enhanced by explaining the logic behind the phrase: That those who use Kollel as a "shield" to avoid service (actively protecting other Jews) are essentially putting others in danger...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I'm hesitant to do so without the original context for the statement, because I can see at least two other possible meanings, and I don't know which the Chazon Ish actually intended.